# Accessing array in jmeter from one controller to another controller

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

> I have written an array in beanshell assertion in jmeter as shown below.

```
String[] myList = {"CM_Name","OwnerID"};
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
{              
vars.put("create_"+myList[i],ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().argumentsAsMap.get(myList[i]));
log.info("create_"+myList[i]);
}
```

I want myList[] to be accessible in another beanshell assertion which is located in another controller.
I have tried this

```
vars.put("myArr",myList);
```

But it didn't worked. What can i do to retrieve the above String array in another beanshell assertion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vars.put()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method expects [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) only as the second argument therefore you cannot put an array there, the solutions are in:

1. Use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method like:

   ```
   vars.putObject("myArr", myList);
   ```

   Later on you will be able to access it like:

   ```
   String [] myList = vars.getObject("myArr");
   ```
2. Use [bsh.shared namespace](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) like:

   In first assertion:

   ```
    bsh.shared.myArr = myList
   ```

   In second assertion:

   ```
    String [] myList = bsh.shared.myArr
   ```

   This way you will even be able to share objects between different Thread Groups.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more Beanshell-related tips and tricks

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) to let a key point to an Object of any type.

Note you will *have* to use [getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String)) to retrieve it in the later assertion. If you don't, You'll get a `ClassCastException` of some sort.

It is your job to keep `Strings` and `Objects` from being messed up.

Protip: **never** store alternatively strings and objects under the same variable name. This actually opens a <s>little door to hell</s> vulnerability, where your script will sprout <s>demons</s> Exceptions from some place but the culprit will be in an entirely different script. Source: I inherited from a script that does that everywhere.

Comment: Thank for your help.